# E-Load System in java

Tags: java

Hi guys I'm Dale and I'm still a newbie in java. I have project that needs to be finished but I'm having a trouble with my codes. 
Description: I want to make a java program that will ask the user to choose from the menu. 1. for E-load 2. for search load record and 4. Transfer and delete. The 3 should be with the E-load which is create a record menu. In other words, create while updating. In 1, I want to ask the user to choose from 3 network service providers and then input the amount-load he wants last ask for payment.Whatever the amount-load input by the user should be stored whatever the network service provider the user chose in a text file. Ex, if he chose Globe telecom it will be stored to salesGlobe.ex Inside the text file comntains
       Globe/100
       Smart/0
       Sun/0
       total Sales/100
    next if you did another transaction, and loaded an amount from smart like 50, it should be like this Globe/100 next line Smart/50 next line Sun/0 next line total Sales/150
     1. E-load
    2. Search Record
    3. Delete and transfer
    1
    Enter the network of your choice: 0
    "You chose globe telecom"
      Enter the 11 mobile number: 091787898787
    Enter the load amount: 100
    "The load 100 will be loaded to your number 091787898787"
    Enter the payment: 101.0
    Your change is 1.0
     conitue? n
   Please also help me out how to transfer and delete a data in a text file the whole system is in JOptionPane

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CRUD { //---------class opening-------------// 
    String strInputMsg="", strInputNum, strInputNetwork, strInputAge, strNumber = " ", strLoad = " ";
    double change, amount, load;
    int intInputMsg, choice;
    int intExist=0;
    String network[] = {"Globe", "Smart", "Sun"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        CRUD method = new CRUD();
        char ans;


            method.menuRecord();




    }//-----------close main-------------------//

    //-------------------------user define method-------------------------------------------//
    public void menuRecord() throws IOException{

        strInputMsg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1-add"
        +"\n2-search"
        +"\n3-update"
        +"\n4-delete"
        +"\n5-exit");

        intInputMsg = Integer.parseInt(strInputMsg);

        switch(intInputMsg){
        case 1: this.addRecord(); break;  //----accessing attributes------// 
        case 2: this.searchRecord(); break;
        case 3: this.updateRecord(); break;
        case 4: this.deleteRecord(); break;
        case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exit"); break;
        default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "out of the list");
        }

    }//close menu

    //---------------------------------------------add record--------------------------------//

    //no returning value

    //===========================================CREATE==============================================
    public void addRecord() throws IOException{


        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter ("D:\\emprec.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);
        File orig_outfile = new File("D:\\emprec.txt");
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(orig_outfile));
        String line=null;

        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input choice"));

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose " + network[0]);
                strInputNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 11 - digit number");
                load = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the load you want"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount " + String.format("%.2f", load) + " will be loaded to your mobile number " + strInputNum);
                amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));

                while(true)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient amount");
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));

                        if(amount < load)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient amount");
                            amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            change = amount - load;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount " + String.format("%.2f", load) + " has been loaded to your mobile number " + strInputNum + "\nYour change is " + String.format("%.2f", change) );
                            break;
                        }
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose " + network[1]);
                strInputNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 11 - digit number");
                load = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the load you want"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount " + String.format("%.2f", load) + " will be loaded to your mobile number " + strInputNum);
                amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));

                while(true)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient amount");
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));

                        if(amount < load)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient amount");
                            amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            change = amount - load;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount " + String.format("%.2f", load) + " has been loaded to your mobile number " + strInputNum + "\nYour change is " + String.format("%.2f", change) );
                            break;
                        }
                }               break;

            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose " + network[2]);
                strInputNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 11 - digit number");
                load = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the load you want"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount " + String.format("%.2f", load) + " will be loaded to your mobile number " + strInputNum);
                amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));

                while(true)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient amount");
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));

                        if(amount < load)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient amount");
                            amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for payment"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            change = amount - load;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount " + String.format("%.2f", load) + " has been loaded to your mobile number " + strInputNum + "\nYour change is " + String.format("%.2f", change) );
                            break;
                        }
                }

                break;
        }

                outFile.append(network[choice] +"/" +strInputNum +"/" + load);
                outFile.newLine();
                outFile.close();

    } //---------------close add method-------------------//

    //===========================================SEARCH===========================================

    public void searchRecord() throws IOException
    {

        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Search mobile network: "));
        File orig_outfile = new File("D:\\emprec.txt");
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(orig_outfile));

        String line = null;

        while((line=infile.readLine())!=null)
        {

            String strNetworkinfile[] = line.split("/");
            if(strNetworkinfile[0].matches(network[choice])){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strNetworkinfile[1] + " " + strNetworkinfile[2]);
                intExist = 1;
                infile.close();
                break;
            }//close if

            else {
            intExist=0; 
            }//close else
        }//close while

        if (intExist==0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No record found.");
        }// close if
    }//close search method

    //======================================UPDATE=============================================

    public void updateRecord() throws IOException{

        File temp = new File("D:\\temprec.txt");
        PrintWriter temp_outfile = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(temp));



        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Search mobile network: "));
    File orig_outfile = new File("D:\\emprec.txt");
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(orig_outfile));

    String line = null;

    while((line=infile.readLine())!=null)
    {

            String strNetworkinfile[] = line.split("/");
            if(strNetworkinfile[0].matches(network[choice]))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strNetworkinfile[1] + " " + strNetworkinfile[2]);
                strNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input name to edit: ");
                strLoad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input age to edit: ");
                temp_outfile.println(strNetworkinfile[0] + "/" + strNumber + "/" + strLoad);
                temp_outfile.flush();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfuly updated!");

                intExist = 1;
                infile.close();
                break;
            }//close if

            else {
            intExist=0; 
            }//close else
    }//close while

    if (intExist==0){
        temp_outfile.append(line);
        temp_outfile.flush();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No record found.");
    }// close if

    temp_outfile.close();
    orig_outfile.delete();
    temp.renameTo(orig_outfile);

    }//close update

    public void deleteRecord()throws IOException
    {
        File temp = new File ("D:\\temprec.txt");
        PrintWriter temp_outfile=new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(temp));


        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Search mobile network: "));
        File orig_outfile=new File ("D:\\emprec.txt");//open the original file
        BufferedReader inFile= new BufferedReader (new FileReader(orig_outfile));

        String Line=null;

        while ((Line=inFile.readLine())!=null){//Alol 2-3. Search and Retrieve record to emprec.txt
        String strNetworkinFile[]=Line.split("/");//pasahan sa gi chop nga information
        if(strNetworkinFile[0].matches(network[choice])){//Algol 4. Determine

            }//if Close
        else {  
            temp_outfile.println(Line);             }//Close Else
        }//While Close
        inFile.close();
        temp_outfile.close();
        orig_outfile.delete();//Dlete the original file emprec.txt
        temp.renameTo(orig_outfile);//Rename temprec.txt to emprec.txt
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,strInputAge+ "Sucessfully Deleted ...");
        }//close Delete Method
    }
//---------------------close class-----------------------//
```

Comment: Hi Dale. Explain what you're having problems with clearly, don't just put up a wall of text like that. "Ugly" questions don't get answered.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).